# DocuSign Connect vs EventNotification attribute in createEnvelope call

Tags: docusignapi

We are doing an integration with DocuSign where users can submit documents stored in our system to DocuSign to get the documents signed. We have the DocuSign Connect feature working in our demo account. We can process messages from DocuSign successfully.

We were concerned that getting users to add a Connect Configuration themselves may be too challenging for some and it will be error-prone.

I see now in the documentation that it is possible to automatically get DocuSign to push notifications by passing the information in the EventNotification attribute when we call createEnvelope. Is this an acceptable way to get push notifications from DocuSign? Will this cause issues with getting the integration certified?

Is there any other way to get Connect configured easily in customer accounts?

Comment: You would want the admin or API account to have the connect configuration, not each user. You can do it on an envelope base if your requirements for what goes through connect and what doesn't changes on an envelope to envelope basis. Otherwise your 1 config should be an easy to manage catch-all

Comment: Are the Connect configurations at the account level?

Comment: Yes they are, you can limit what users are impacted in the configuration. But they're account wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but I wanted, for the record to have answers, since it's important to anyone who may be reading this.

> We see now in the documentation that it is possible to automatically
>   get DocuSign to push notifications by passing the information in the
>   EventNotification attribute when we call createEnvelope. Is this an
>   acceptable way to get push notifications from DocuSign?

Yes, it is. It's a very good way in fact, to reduce polling and make your app better. We highly recommend that you use EvenNotification and sign-up for events going through a webhook to your app such that you can handle them in your code only when they occur, instead of polling DocuSign APIs repeatedly.

> Will this cause issues with getting the integration certified?

The opposite is true. If you use polling you may have issues being certified. Using connect events with a webhook is one way to avoid the need for excessive polling which could cause issues with the certification.

> Is there any other way to get Connect configured easily in customer
>   accounts?

You can configure connect like you suggested using **EventNotification** at the envelope level. This approach works well for ISVs since you don't need your customers to have admin access to their accounts.
The other option is account-level connect configuration, which does require admin level access and there are some other limitations. This approach adds the connect webhook for all envelopes in the account. So it may or may not be better, depending on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, Inbar. We went ahead and proceeded with making it add EventNotification information for every envelope we create and it has been working this way for years without issue. We really want to only get notifications for the envelopes created by our integration so it does make sense to only do it for some envelopes. It's a little more data to store, but it results in less load for us and DS so I think this is the right way.

Comment: Sarel, do you mind marking this question (really questions plural) as answered? I appreciate it!